# Echo user input from one .php file to echo on another

Tags: php, session-variables, session-state

Im having trouble getting the user input entered from one page (index.php) to be echo'd on the next page (receipt.php) but for some reason it keeps saying "undefined index: cleanEmail ...". Im using "session start" for all my pages.

So far iv got a variable made in tools.php called "cleanEmail" that will post the data entered into the specified field from the index.php page(email field in this case) and i tried calling it on the receipt.php page using echo and `$_SESSION['cleanEmail']`.

Iv tried `include(index.php);` in the receipt.php page but for some reason after doing that the index and receipt page will be stuck forever in loading and never actually load the page, iv tried `include(tools.php);` in the receipt page and pretty much crashes the index page for some reason.

Relevant code from tools.php:

```php
<?php
session_start();
include("bookings.txt");
?>

$cleanEmail = $_POST['cust']['email'];
```

Relevant code from index.php:

```php
<?php
require("receipt.php");
?>
<?php
session_start();
$title = "Lunardo Cinema";
$style="style.css";
include("tools.php")
?>

<form method="post" action="https://generic_website_name/receipt.php">

<label for="email">Email</label>
<span class ="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
   <input type="text" id="cust-email" name="cust[email]" placeholder="JohnMoreDoe@gmail.com" >
</form>
```

Relevant code from receipt.php:

```php
<?php
session_start();
$title = "Receipt Page";

?>

<?php

echo("{$_SESSION['cleanEmail']}"."<br />");

?>
```

what i need the code to do is When an email is entered in by a user in the input field for email, it will save that input in session and then i can later call it on another page using the same session.

If you want to see all 3 .php files with all the code in it i can upload a link to download a .rar file containg the 3 .php files and the .css file (assuming we are allowed to post links here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never store `$_SESSION['cleanEmail']` in **tools.php**

`$cleanEmail = $_POST['cust']['email']` will not becomes session variable

To store session variable, you have to write like this:

```php
<?php

$cleanEmail = $_POST['cust']['email']
$_SESSION['cleanEmail'] = $cleanEmail;

?>
```

Comment: Iv added in the code you provided into "tools.php" and im no longer getting a error in receipt.php saying "undefined index: cleanEmail" but nothing is showing up on receipt page (iv only got ```echo("{$_SESSION['cleanEmail']}"."<br />");``` on there but it wont echo anything even though iv input data into the field from the index.php page)

Comment: correct and write this `echo( $_SESSION['cleanEmail'] . "<br />" );` in receipt.php

Comment: i just tried it, and same thing still wont echo the email iv entered :/ the error is gone so it must be storing something in $cleanEmail but not sure if its just not echo it or if its not actually storing the input.

Comment: I just edited my answer, if you need to keep the `$cleanEmail` variable for further use